# enable numbers in Magento Quick Search

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I need to allow to use numbers in quick search to differentiate products that are called like this examples :

- box 1800
- box 1100
- box 5500

But it looks like the numbers are ignored in the search. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Magento uses `MATCH` `AGAINST` in it's SQL query used for searching products in Fulltext mode.

Most probably your configuration is set to fulltext (it's done in:
`Admin > Catalog > Catalog Search and find Search Type`) and your MySQL server is **configured with `ft_min_word_len` higher than 4.**

To check the default configuration login to MySQL and type in:

```
mysql> show variables like 'ft%';
+--------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value          |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| ft_boolean_syntax        | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len          | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len          | 4              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file         | (built-in)     |
+--------------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

To change this value open up your MySQL config (e.g. `/etc/my.cnf`) and search for/change line to:

`ft_min_word_len = 1` where 1 is the minimum length of word

Restart your MySQL server:
`service mysql restart`

Reindex data in Magento.

Second solution is to rewrite class `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext` and in function `prepareResult:330` add code block that would handle words shorter than 5 characters with `LIKE` statement.

Comment: can you plz take a look at my question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311115/magento-2-truncate-search-term-in-quick-search-if-the-last-4-digits-are-number